# How can hash.values.all? == false return true when all the values are not false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can `@filters.values.all? == false` return `true` when `@filters.values' clearly shows three true values?

EDIT: And how *do* you check to see if every value is false?

EDIT2: Because people want to copy and paste an arbitrary code snippet:

```
f = { 
  self: true,
  clear: true,
  something1: false,
  something2: true
}

f.all? == false
==> false

f.values.all? == false
==> true

f.values
==> [true, true, false, true]
```

[image: Filters hash witchcraft]

Comment: `true`, `true`, `false`, `true`. Are these four values *all* `true`?

Comment: Note that `@filters.all? == false` is equivalent to `x == false` where `x = @filters.all?`. Maybe you meant `.all? { |x| x == false }`? That’d be better written as `not @filters.any?`, though.

Comment: I'm trying to see if all values are all false.

Comment: Please, post the code you are having trouble with. The code. Not a photograph of the code. Not a link to the code. The code. See how to construct a [mcve], [ask], and the [help] for details,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enumerable#all?`, from the docs:

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method
>   returns true if the block never returns false or nil. If the block is
>   not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of { |obj| obj } which will
>   cause all? to return true when none of the collection members are
>   false or nil.

That means that `@filters.values.all?` will return false unless every attribute is set to true (or truthy, to be more accurate) so, if you want to know when every item is `false`, then you will have to pass a block to `all?` and check each value, like this:

```
@filters.values.all? { |value| value == false } #=> true
```

**UPDATE**

Previous answer stated that also `!@filters.values.all?` will return `true` when all `values` are `truthy`, and that's true, but it will also return `true` if only one is set to `false`; in fact, it will always return `true` unless all `values` are set to `true`.

Comment: @JustusEapen Please check updated answer, there was a flaw on the first option.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `all?` method will call the block with each
For eaxmple `enumerable.all?` will be executed like this:

```
enumerable.each {|x| x }
hash_enumerable.each {|k, _v| k }
```

So when the enumerable is a hash the block firt params will be the key....

Answer (score 1):

To check if all the values in your hash is `false`, try this:

```
temp = {self: false, clear: false, lorem: false, ipsum: false}
temp.values.uniq == [false]
#=> true

temp2 = {self: true, clear: true, lorem: false, ipsum: true}
temp2.values.uniq == [false]
#=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter, though slightly less clear, way to determine if all of the values are false is to simply ask if any of them are true and negate the response:

```
@filters = {foo: false, bar: true, baz: false}
!@filters.values.any? #=> false

@filters = {foo: false, bar: false, baz: false}
!@filters.values.any? #=> true
```